# How to change JAXB used by JBoss AS 7.1 to JDK 6's JAXB

Tags: jaxb, jboss7.x, java-6, docx4j

I have a Spring web app deployed on Jboss AS 7.1 and uses JDK 1.6.
Also use docx4j to deal with ms office word files.

Jboss forces its own jaxb implementation.
However docx4j needed the JDK 1.6's jaxb implementation.

How can i use jdk's jaxb instead of jboss's jaxb?

Answer (score 0):

You can place a `jaxb.properties` file in the same package as a domain model to override the default JAXB implementation used.

**jaxb.properties**

As an example below is what the contents of the file would look like to specify EclipseLink MOXy as your JAXB provider.  To specify an alternate [JAXB (JSR-222)](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) provider you just change the value of the property:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html